# Help - Updates failed and lost all files

Tags: 14.04, 12.04

Our laptop initially had 12.04 LTS, and then we upgraded to 14.04 LTS. But the 14.04 version had so many errors, I had to disable further updates.

Skip a year later, laptop crashes frequently and my father suggested re-enabling the updates. I enable them, updating process starts and doesn't end. It got to around 70% and stopped. I used the power key to shutdown the laptop.
The next day, my mother calls me and tells me that the laptop wouldn't start. I go back home and I try starting it. It doesn't start up at all.

I had several options and I chose to revert to 12.04. Unfortunately, that just erased ALL files. Everything. 3 years worth of work gone in a minute.

I believe it was a factory reset, but I am not sure.

Is it possible to restore some of the files?

Thanks!

Comment: *But the 14.04 version had so many errors, I had to disable further updates* <- So you took the most illogical path. Errors or glitches tend to be corrected with... Updates! And yes, by the look of it, it was a reset to a factory installed image. So, before anything else, please edit and update your question (pun intended) with the brand/model of the said laptop.

Comment: There isn't an option in Ubuntu to `factory reset`.  Also, any revert or fresh install will only affect the system-wide folders... the files that are installed by default in the default install folders such as, `/bin`, `/usr/bin/`, `/sbin`, etc.  A user's data is in the `/home` folder.  That folder would not be touched.  Also any other user created folders would not be touched.  Even a fresh install would not touch those folders.  The only way those folders would be touched is if an option to `format` the partition was selected.  If that were the case you would need to run...(continued)

Comment: ...you would have to run a [recover files from deleted partition](https://www.google.com/#q=ubuntu+recover+files+from+deleted+partition) type recovery process.

Comment: how did you do "factory reset" exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `/home` folder along with all your files are missing from the drive it's the results of a deleted or reformatted partition.  You had best not use the drive while you perform steps to recover your data.

A very robust application for this is [Testdisk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi9-orsgu_PAhVJMj4KHeuNAu8QFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cgsecurity.org%2Fwiki%2FTestDisk_Step_By_Step&usg=AFQjCNFMaTiY0Queb3srLksaEkchh_LHqw&sig2=c8fYoPz5X2bXaie9LLl7CA&bvm=bv.136593572,d.cWw).

**Using Testdisk to recover files**

1. Boot from DVD/CD/USB drive as not to use the HDD any more.  (even better would be to take a full copy onto another HDD and recover from there)
2. Install `Testdisk`.
   *(The dollar sign `$` is the command prompt.  It's showing that you are typing a command in the terminal.  The text highlighted in bold are the actual items that you click on while performing the steps.)*

```
        $ sudo apt install testdisk
```

3. Run these steps (taken from [TestDisk Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and tested by me to recover files):

```
    $ sudo testdisk
    1: Select Create       - ENTER
    2: Select Create       - ENTER
    3: Select Disk         - Proceed
    4: Select Intel        - ENTER
    5: Select Analyse      - ENTER
    6: Select Quick Search - ENTER
```

This procedure is to recover your important files.  The steps provided will give you options to try to recover the entire partion.  If that fails you'll then have an option to recover individual files.  Try to have a media such as a USB drive to recover your important data to.

Comment: *Now* it's a robust answer and worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Agreed. +1  But it's still not clear what happened but there's also the possibility of something vendor specific, some recovery tool from an image or recovery partition not default in Ubuntu by installed by the vendor. The way OP worded the question suggests it's a factory installed Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Even a factory restore of a factory installed Ubuntu wouldn't by default overwrite the the disk with zeros (or some other form of scrubbing the physical data on the drive).  So it sounds like the OP's main concern is some method to recover his data.  As long and he doesn't use the hard drive before running data recovery tools he had a chance to prevent a total lost.

Comment: @L.D.James What part of my comments made you think that I think the data is unrecoverable? My comment above was meant to be complementary. I wasn't arguing against your answer, *au contraire* I upvoted it. Not long ago we had a chat where most of times I felt I was talking to a wall but in the end you understood (an hour or so later but better later then never). Is my English so bad that I'm inadvertently misleading you? Or is it that you don't like me? It's fine, many don't either. After all I'm a condescending a-hole.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I can't help your thinking you're talking to a wall.  It appears that you have some resentment for many of my comments.  I can't control how you view my input and comments.  But all my participation is an effort to offer positive  productivity for SE and the community.  It's my intentions to be a amicable as possible.  Maybe with time you'll start to recognize my good intentions to share and participate.  The `wall` reference doesn't sound like the best compliment.  But I hope you'll eventually start to realize the amicable intentions of what I type.

Comment: @L.D.James Again, you're misunderstanding and misreading my intentions. I don't have any resentment about your comments although I should point out that some, in our other chat, came out as arrogant or, at least, like those from a politician dodging a question. I consider your participation brilliant and you have the rep to go with it but that doesn't mean you're infallible. Nobody is. When I make mistakes I like to be corrected and I often thank whoever correct me. You on the other hand seem to take those suggestions on a personal level, like someone is attacking you and that's ridiculous.

Comment: My reference to in the comment section about the data was mainly to reemphasize to the OP, not to use the hard drive while before spending time in data recovery.  I see quiet often I make grammar errors such as in my previous message when I used the `had` a chance in past tense when I mean `has` a chance as in current. (By the way, I see you typed while I was typing).  I realize that you are misinterpreting my actions.  But I wouldn't refer to it as `ridiculous`.  As I mentioned before, I hope you will soon see things in a different light regarding me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47245/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-l-d-james).

Comment: I booted from the HDD. This may be a mistake, but it was all I could do. 
I did all the steps as mentioned. It found 4 partitions, and I selected the biggest one (I assume it's that one). Then I selected 'Write', as it was the only option available, except for deeper search and quit. I'm rebooting now.

Comment: Oh well... it seems that a new problem has appeared. Once I boot the laptop (Dell laptop), I get this:
Loading DRMK V8... and then it says that it loaded DRMK Version 8, something about dell copyright and that's it. I get something like C:\: and I can write. That's it.

Comment: More news... 
As it turns out, what I did erased my OS. I plugged in my USB with ubuntu 12.04 (Not related in any way with the factory reset from earlier) and I started the installation process. Apparently, it couldn't detect and OS. This is the most confusing thing ever. I don't think I'll ever get anything out of this.

Comment: Booting to the hard drive you want to repair wasn't all you could do.  You could have booted to the Ubuntu Live USB or DVD.  Booting to the problem hard drive caused more damage because each time you boot to it it writes it making data retrieval harder.

Comment: I'm glad the answer is helping you!  Because of this extended chat-like discussion in the comments, will you place your up comments [here-in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47245/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-l-d-james).  If it's more than 10 or 15 minutes between communication use @L.D.James to give me a notification to check the screen.